# Variable inside a regular expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

name=['hello','hi','ok']
text='"hello Paul" "are you there" "hi Jessie" "ok thank you"'
result=[]
for i in name:
    result.append(re.findall(r'"'+str(name)+'.*?"',str(text)))
```

I want to get

```
[['"hello Paul"'], ['"hi Jessie"'], ['"ok thank you"']]
```

but I get

```
[['"hello Paul"', '" "', '" "'], ['"hello Paul"', '" "', '" "'], ['"hello Paul"', '" "', '" "']]
```

How can I fix my code to produce the desired result above?

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your format of your input in the first place. That being said, you could use a so called *lookaround* and then split on this one:

```
import re
names = ['hello','hi','ok']
texts = '"hello Paul" "are you there" "hi Jessie" "ok thank you"'

rx = re.compile('(?<=") (?=")')
result = [text for text in rx.split(texts) for name in names if text.strip('"').startswith(name)]
print(result)
```

Which produces

```
['"hello Paul"', '"hi Jessie"', '"ok thank you"']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/EMLOjI).

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
import re
    
name=['hello','hi','ok']
text='"hello Paul" "are you there" "hi Jessie" "ok thank you"'
result= re.findall('("[^"]*(?:' + "|".join(name) + ')[^"]*")',str(text))
```

**output**

```
['"hello Paul"', '"hi Jessie"', '"ok thank you"']
```

**explaination**

`" ... "` match if the string is contained between `'"'`

`[^"]*` match all characters except `'"'` so every character inside a `'"'` closed string

`(?:' + "|".join(name) + ')` match one of the keys you give, the `"|"` means `or` and the `?:` means that the group is a non capturing group

`(...)` is a capturing grout that captures all in a string contained in `'"'` and containing one of the keys

**oline demo**

[here on Pythex with preocomplied keys](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%22%5B%5E%22%5D*(%3F%3Ahello%7Chi%7Cok)%5B%5E%22%5D*%22)&test_string=%22hello%20Paul%22%20%22are%20you%20there%22%20%22hi%20Jessie%22%20%22ok%20thank%20you%22&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Please read [answer]. You could significantly improve the quality of your answers by including explanations, justifications, and references instead of just saying "try this"